# Is there a better alternative to "column NOT IN (1,2,3)"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Saw some major performance differences between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS,

Was wondering, out of interest, if it would be possible to optimise this query?

```
--  (ignore the SELECT *)
SELECT *
FROM `comments`
WHERE comment_id NOT IN (65,64,63)
ORDER BY `comment_id` DESC
```

Comment: Note that they behave completely different if there are NULL's involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `comment_id` is the primary key for the table `comments`, I don't think this can be improved upon. I don't see why you would want to try, either. Your condition is on the primary key, so the query should use the index.

MySQL puts all its data "behind" the primary key. Or, as [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) puts it:

> Every InnoDB table has a special index called the clustered index where the data for the rows is stored. Typically, the clustered index is synonymous with the primary key.
>
> (...)
>
> - If you do not define a PRIMARY KEY for your table, MySQL locates the first UNIQUE index where all the key columns are NOT NULL and InnoDB uses it as the clustered index.

So if your query uses the primary key, that is *the fastest way* to retrieve your data.

---

What does the explain plan say?

And why do you feel the need to try to optimise at all?

---

The difference in performance between `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` is only when using a sub-select to "fill" the IN-list.

Compare

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comments c
WHERE c.author_id NOT IN (
    SELECT a.author_id
    FROM authors a
    WHERE a.first_name = 'Jay'
);
```

with

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comments c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM authors a
    WHERE c.author_id = a.author_id
      AND a.first_name = 'Jay'
);
```

although I would use

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN authors a
   ON (c.author_id = a.author_id AND a.first_name = 'Jay')
WHERE a.author_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if there is better way to do what I am doing. :)

Comment: @Jay, well, as the saying goes, the proof of the pudding is in the eating. Try a few different ways and compare them.